# Magento2 factory object inject parameters

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, factory, object-manager

I have created a Model with a Resource model to it and a collection.

In `MyModel` I have defined the property

```
public $myProperty;
```

However, when I try to do

```
$myModel = $this->MyModuleFactory->create(['myProperty'=>5]);
var_dump($myModel->myProperty);
```

The value of `myProperty` is always `NULL`. How can I set the `$myProperty` value to `5` ?

Comment: Could you post the full code ?

Comment: i got the answer that did the job, so no need :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add 'myProperty' to the constructor aslo

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    $myProperty = null; //because this is not a class instance make it default to null otherwise the object manager will not know what to do with it
){
   ...
   $this->myProperty = $myProperty;
}
```

and instantiate your class like this

```
$data = ['myProperty'=>5];
$this->MyModuleFactory->create(['data' => $data]);
```

Comment: ah, when i did $this->MyModuleFactory->create( ['myProperty'=>5]); it got set, the create(['data' => $data]) did not work ?